# What is wrong with MySQL syntax? Unable to insert

Tags: mysql, sql

Upon trying to insert into database, I get MySQLSyntaxErrorException, meaning that my SQL is wrong. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it

```
    INSERT INTO players (uuid, username) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uuid=VALUES(e4b3cfb9-0106-4bde-897d-d47465bcf594), username=VALUES(Realmm)
```

Comment: Beware that your SQL tool is not displaying full error messages.

Comment: Have you checked MySQL documentation whether your syntax is correct or not???  You can't write SQL in whatever format, and expect MySQL to understand and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you *really* want, then the syntax is more like this:

```
INSERT INTO players (uuid, username)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uuid ='e4b3cfb9-0106-4bde-897d-d47465bcf594',
                            username = VALUES(Realmm);
```

Even this might result in an error.  `Realmm` doesn't seem to be part of the update.  If you want `'Realmm'`, then you need strings there too:

```
INSERT INTO players (uuid, username)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uuid ='e4b3cfb9-0106-4bde-897d-d47465bcf594',
                            username = 'Realmm';
```

The *typical* approach to avoid an error would be:

```
INSERT INTO players (uuid, username)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uuid = VALUES(uuid);
```

Sometimes additional columns are set, such as a counter or update date.  But keys which are (presumably) part of a unique index are not usually set to constant values.

Comment: So with the second approach, where does 'Realmm' get inserted? Also, uuid is the primary key if that helps.

Comment: @JamesAndrew . . . It doesn't.  But if you want that as a string, it should be surrounded by single quotes.